# Getting exception when trying to insert or update multiple rows in the table

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to Insert and update multiple rows from a Datatable into database table.
Below is the code to pass Datatable to Stored procedure:

```
 DataTable dtUserRights = new DataTable();
        PropertyInfo[] piT = typeof(clsRightsAL).GetProperties(); //Gets all column values with there datatype
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in piT)
        {
              //create a datacolumn for each property
              DataColumn dc = new DataColumn(pi.Name, pi.PropertyType);
              dtUserRights.Columns.Add(dc);

        }

        try
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            for (int item = 0; item < objUserRightsALLst.Count; item++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dtUserRights.NewRow();


                for (int property = 0; property < dtUserRights.Columns.Count; property++)
                {
                    dr[property] = piT[property].GetValue(objUserRightsALLst[item], null);
                }

                dtUserRights.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            objCmd = new SqlCommand();
            objCmd.CommandText = "sp_AD_InsertUpdateGroupRights";
            objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            objCmd.Connection = con;
            objCmd.Parameters.Clear();
            SqlParameter tableParameter =  objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GroupRightslist", dtUserRights);
            tableParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
 intCount = objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
```

Below is the SP I'm calling:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_AD_InsertUpdateGroupRights]  
@GroupRightslist as  [dbo].[GroupRightsList] ReadOnly  
AS  
BEGIN   
if Not Exists(Select intID from tblADGroupRights where intID = (Select l.intID from @GroupRightslist l))  
Begin  
  insert into tblADGroupRights(IntGroupID,intMenuID,blAdd,blEdit,blView,blGrant,blStatus,strUserCreated
) Select l.IntGroupID,l.intMenuID,l.blAdd,l.blEdit,l.blView,l.blGrant,l.blStatus,
l.strBy from GroupRightslist l   

End     
 else    

  begin  
update A set blAdd = l.blAdd,blEdit = l.blEdit,blView = l.blView,blGrant = l.blGrant   
 FROM  tblADGroupRights A INNER JOIN @GroupRightslist l on A.intID = l.intID  
where A.intID = l.intID     
end
END
```

When im passing single row to Stored procedure the data is getting inserted, but when datatable is having multiple records , i'm getting Exception:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

And my update Query is not at all working.

My User Defined Table Type:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[GroupRightsList] AS TABLE(
[intID] [int] NULL,
[intProfileID] [int] NULL,
[IntGroupID] [int] NULL,
[intMenuID] [int] NULL,
[blAdd] [bit] NULL,
[blEdit] [bit] NULL,
[blView] [bit] NULL,
[blGrant] [bit] NULL,
[blStatus] [bit] NULL,
[strBy] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)
```

I'm aware that this exception usually raises when the Select query return more than 1 value and we have not handled it properly, but in my scenario as Im using User Type table i have seen many sites where they have shown it in the same way i have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

it is purely an sp error. It means that in your sp you have a subquery that is returning more than one record which is not permitted. Most probably below is the line

```
Select intID from tblADGroupRights where intID = (Select l.intID from @GroupRightslist l)
```

Either change it to

```
Select intID from tblADGroupRights where intID = (Select Top 1 l.intID from @GroupRightslist l)
```

or

```
Select intID from tblADGroupRights where intID in (Select l.intID from @GroupRightslist l)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'm able to insert but my update query is not working still.

Comment: I was not getting any error but it seems the control was not reaching to update query. It is resolved now. Thank you